# How to issue warning/error when using older version of Doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

I'm planning to use doxygen to document a project. It's an OSS project whose current documentation is of questionable quality. The reason I've decided to go with doxygen is because from version 1.8, doxygen has added support for Markdown (text formatter; think we use it on this site too).

A concern of mine is for the people who might end up using older versions of Doxygen (for example, it hasn't been updated in the current Ubuntu LTS release).

Is it possible to add some setting or marking in the Doxyfile (doxygen configuration file), such that it will issue an error/warning if someone tries to generate the documentation using an older version of doxygen?

(Ideally, explaining the cause of error as well)

Answer (score 1):

Doxygen itself provides a sort-of warning for these circumstances.  If your doxyfile includes things like `MARKDOWN_SUPPORT = YES` and the incumbent doxygen is not one that supports markdown, then you do get a warning that the option is unrecognised.

`Warning: ignoring unsupported tag 'MARKDOWN_SUPPORT'...`

Alternatively, you could implement some script that parses the return from `doxygen -v` which will either return a handy '1.8.5' or the usage help, including a line `version 1.y.z` - so something based around `doxygen -v | grep "1\."` would extract a suitable line.